# Unity updating data in fire base but APK not updating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I created a app in unity and firebase

the app is simple
it have one input and button
in unity editor data is updating in fire base
but after exporting the APK from unity and installing in mobile it is not updating the data in fire base and not showing me any error.

i have two scripts

also i tried it on different mobiles and emulator like nox player game loop

but problem is still same any one please help me

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro; // Add this line for TextMeshPro components

public class FirebaseDatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    DatabaseReference reference;
    public TMP_InputField inputField; // Reference to the TMP Input Field in the Unity UI
    public TMP_Text resultText; // Reference to the TMP Text component in the Unity UI
    public TMP_Text logText; // Reference to the TMP Text component for displaying logs

    void Start()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
            Log("Firebase initialized!");
        });
    }

    // Function to write text data to the "MyNode1" node
    public void WriteTextToFirebase()
    {
        string text = inputField.text; // Get text from the TMP Input Field
        reference.Child("MyNode1").SetValueAsync(text).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Handle the error
                Log("Error writing to Firebase: " + task.Exception);
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Log("Text written to Firebase successfully!");
            }
        });
    }

    // Function to read text data from the "MyNode1" node
    public void ReadTextFromFirebase()
    {
        reference.Child("MyNode1").GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Handle the error
                Log("Error reading from Firebase: " + task.Exception);
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                // Get the data
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                string text = snapshot.Value.ToString();

                // Display the text in the TMP Text component
                resultText.text = "Text from Firebase: " + text;
                Log("Text from Firebase: " + text);
            }
        });
    }

    // Function to log messages to the TMP Text component
    void Log(string message)
    {
        // Append the message to the existing log text
        logText.text += message + "\n";

        // Optionally, you can limit the log text length to avoid performance issues
        if (logText.text.Length > 1000)
        {
            logText.text = logText.text.Substring(logText.text.Length - 1000);
        }
    }
}
```